# WorkManager instances keep alive even after the app is uninstalled (?)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I've been trying out the new Android [WorkManager API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) and it seems to work fine. However I noticed something while testing my app: before creating a new periodic worker instance, I check for status to avoid creating more than one:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(myTag)
            .observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { status ->
                // creates a new worker if status returns nothing
            })
```

The first time app launched the status returned nothing and a new one was created, but then I needed to uninstall my app and when it launched again there was already a worker created, from the logs:

```
WorkStatus{mId='UUID', mState=ENQUEUED, mOutputData=androidx.work.Data@0, mTags=[tag, tagName]}]
```

I know the API is still in alpha, but I was wondering if this is expected and if this won't be a problem. I think that if user uninstalls your app these background tasks should be removed too. I've been trying to find some information related to this, but I couldn't so far. 
Has anyone seen this or can anyone point me a documentation or something similar?

Thank you for your help

Comment: odd.. are you reinstalling the app immediately? Maybe work will be discarded automatically after a delay/failure to run due to uninstallation?

Comment: Your data may have been restored automatically when your app was reinstalled, due to `android:allowBackup`.

Comment: Yes, @Pawel I'm reinstalling the app almost immediately. And it's what I think too: if the worker really keeps alive, maybe after a while it will be discarded dueto failure

Answer (score 2):

**Of course NOT**. Once you uninstall the app there will be no instance of WorkManager.

WorkManager API will work even if your app is process has been killed but not after uninstallation of app. WorkManager API implementation is part of your Application but not Android OS.

Please check your uninstallation again.

Comment: Hi VicJordan. Thank you for your answer. I'm still not sure the worker isn't being kept. During first launch, the `getStatusesByTag` returns nothing, and after reinstallation the status is always returning ENQUEUED. Maybe there is a configuration I'm missing? Also, what exactly you wanted to say with `Please check your uninstallation again.` ?

Comment: @Amanda did you try to set `android:allowBackup="false"` in your AndroidManifest.xml? Please check it once. Regarding uninstallation, I meant that you should to the clean uninstallation. What you can do is, generate `apk`. **Copy**  on your device in Downloads folder. Once copied, remove USB cable and install `apk` by clicking on it. Once installed successfully, delete the `apk` from Downloads folder. Now again copy the `apk` to Downloads folder, install it again and see the behavior.

Comment: I was wondering what would happen if a work was running during the uninstall? would it finish the work and uninstall the app or would it just stop everything and uninstall?